# php how to add edit button inside a table and load data to edit form

Tags: php, html, button

**what i am trying to do:**
loading data from mysql database in a table with edit buttons.

**what is going wrong:**
when clicking on edit buttons it doesn't load the data on the edit form.

**what i have tried:**
i tried the following code at home on Firefox and it worked perfectly. but at work it fails to load the data in Firefox in the edit form and in IE clicking the button does nothing.

```
<?php
echo '<table id="viewAll">';
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<th>Product</th>';
            echo '<th>Status</th>';
            echo '<th>Summary</th>';
            echo '<th>Created</th>';
            echo '<th>Updated</th>';
            echo '<th>Edit</th>';

            echo '</tr>';


            while ($data=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

            echo '<tr align="center">

            <td>'.$data['product'].'</td>
            <td>'.$data['status'].'</td>
            <td align="left">'.$data['summary'].'</td>
            <td>'.$data['created'].'</td>
            <td >'.$data['updated'].'</td>';

            echo "<td><a href=\"editForm.php?id=$data[id]\" style=\"text-decoration: none\"><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Edit\" /></a></td>";

            echo '</tr>';


                }#end of while


            }#end of if



echo '</table>';
?>
```

and then i do:

```
$id=$_GET['id'];



            $query="SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE id='$id'";


            $result = mysqli_query($db,$query) or die( "My query ($query) generated an error: ".mysql_error());

            $data=mysqli_fetch_array($result);





            mysqli_close($db);
```

I use the contents in the data array to load it into the field in the edit form..

unfortunately this doesn't work in IE. clicking edit button doesn't do anything. Can somebody please tell me how to fix it?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this:

```
echo "<td><form action=\"editForm.php\" method=\"get\"><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"id\" value=\"$data['id']\" style=\"text-decoration: none\" /><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Edit\" /></form></td>";
```

That will mean you can still use a button.

Also, I strongly suggest if you are not using tables for tabular data, find an alternative, such as `<div>`s.

And remember to sanitise your SQL queries, or you may be susceptible to SQL injection attacks.
(e.g. `$id=$_GET['id'];` => `$id=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['id']);` where `$conn` is your MySQL connection object).

You can search for any of these things on [Google](//google.com).

Comment: Thanks but i get the following error with your code:
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in F:\PHP Ninja\xampp\htdocs\testdrive\includes\functions.php on line 4`

any idea why? thanks.

Comment: @greenhoodlum What is in `functions.php`?

Comment: Oops - I made an error in my MySQL code (forgot end bracket) - it should read `$id=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['id']);`! I have updated my post.

Comment: I think i fixed it..will test further and come back.

Comment: The code doesn't seem to work on my work server for some reason. i'm using the same browser yet it fails. i'm puzzled.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use `<input type="submit" value="edit" name="edit" />`.

Only `"<a href='editForm.php?id='".$data['id']."' style='text-decoration: none' />Edit</a>"` would be enough in sending you the data to the `editForm.php` page.

PS: submit button can only be used to submit all form elements within the form.

Answer (score 1):

Correct the line where you write the button into this way

```
echo "<td><a href=\"editForm.php?id=$data[id]\" style=\"text-decoration: none\">Edit</a></td>";
```

Clicking the button try to submit a form. But what you want to do is access the page editForm.php

PS: You should read some tutorials about PHP and html to learn best practice ;)

Comment: That works but its not as a button. when i try to add a button it does the same thing on IE.

Comment: @greenhoodlum As I wrote, the '<a>' tag will directly call editForm.php when clicking it. The submit button you used try to submit a form that do not exist. If you really want to integrate a button, you should integrate a '<form>' that will submit correct information to editForm.php

Answer (score 0):

In the while loop in the first PHP script, the line which echoes the edit button is wrong.
You have to use the concatenate function `.` and quotes to get the value in `$data["id"]` 
Your line `echo "<td><a href=\"editForm.php?id=$data[id]\" style=\"text-decoration: none\">Edit</a></td>";` has to be replaced by :

`echo "<td><a href=\"editForm.php?id=".$data['id']."\" style=\"text-decoration: none\">Edit</a></td>";`

Comment: Thanks i'm doing that now but it still fails in IE.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could do this in a nice way with jQuery. Try reading [this](http://api.jquery.com/click/).